# java.lang.RuntimeException unable to instantiate service: java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, intentservice

I was trying to create an activity that start a service (in a new thread). It consists in a layout with two editText and a button called Send. The point is that when I execute the MainActivity, it throws that:

```
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service hikoki.services.NotificationsService: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2237)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1201)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSystemService(ContextWrapper.java:386)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at hikoki.services.NotificationsService.<init>(NotificationsService.java:35)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2234)
06-15 22:32:13.312: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  ... 10 more
```

The code of Main Activity is this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread t= new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(),NotificationsService.class);
                //Intent intent=new Intent("hikoki.services.NotificationsService");
                Log.d(TAG,"sending notificationsService");
                startService(intent);
            }
        };
        t.start();
    }

    protected Context getContext() {    
        return this;
    }
}
```

An the code od NotificationsService is here:

```
public class NotificationsService extends IntentService{
    private static  int TIME_INTERVAL_MILIS=5000;
    private static final int REFRESH=10;
    private  NotificationManager noteManager;
    private static List<FlightStatusNote> flights= new ArrayList<FlightStatusNote>();

    public NotificationsService(){
        super("NotificationsService"); 
        noteManager= NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE)
    }
}
```

and the AndroidManifest is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="hikoki.services"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="hikoki.services.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".FlightStatusService"></service>
    <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".NotificationsService"></service>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you cannot call getSystemService before onStart is called because your context is not initialized.

Comment: @njzk2 thanks for that! I changed it, but it is still not working :/

Comment: Please post the new stack trace, as you are crashing somewhere else now.

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited the post with the new stack trace.

Comment: I know this is slightly off topic, but what are you trying to accomplish, here?  The service that you start will not run on the newly created thread...

Comment: @G.BlakeMeike good question! I'm trying to create a thread that runs in background (it requests to a server for every five minutes, for example. It causes "code pollution" I know, but i din't find a better way). It's strange what you're saying, because I run the program and it's seems to works ok (the thread sleeps, and the "unresponsive aplication" message didn't appeared :S). Please, tell me why are you telling that (because I got confused :S)

Comment: Sort of what I guessed.  If that service is part of your application then, no matter what thread you run startService from, it will run on the main/UI thread.  You will still, eventually, get those ANRs.  Have a look at using service that starts a thread and initializes it as a Looper.  Then use Handler.postDelayed.  A second problem probably, is that your application (process) will be killed eventually.  If you are trying to poll continuously, have a look at the AlarmManager and an IntentService.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You cannot call `getSystemService()` from an initializer (as you originally were) or from the constructor (as you are now). Please override `onCreate()`, and call `getSystemService()` there.

Basically, until `onCreate()` is called (or, more accurately, until after you call `super.onCreate()` from your `onCreate()`), the inherited methods on `Service` are not yet ready for your use.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error. My mistake was that the Service didnt have an empty default constructor. Here's the code that solved it:

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {

    public MyService() { 
         super(null); // That was the lacking constructor
    }

    public MyService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    //...

}
```

Comment: This fixed my issue!